# Remove fragment from backStack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment-backstack

I have ViewPager that has 3 tabs. Tab(2) includes 2 fragments (A) --> (B). Tab(3) includes 2 fragments (C) --> (D).

```
Tab(1)
Tab(2) --> (A) --> (B) 
Tab(3) --> (C) --> (D)
```

Inside of (A) when it's created, variable "isUserLogged" being checked (true/false).
My problem is: Tab(2) gets saved in ViewPager backstack.
So when I hit a button in (D) I want to remove Tab(2) so when it's created again it would check "isUserLogged" again.
This is how I replace fragments:

```
FragmentTransaction trans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        trans.replace(R.id.hostsUlogged_container, new FragmentHostProfile(), "HostUnlogged-HostProfile");
        trans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        trans.addToBackStack("hostUnlogged_screen");
        trans.commit();
```

How do I remove specific fragment with tag ("hostUnlogged_screen") ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove specific fragment by tag as following:

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment=fm.findFragmentByTag("hostUnlogged_screen");
fm.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```